# Table cell content scrollable is not working on IE 11

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a div inside table cells. Content of them will dynamically change. I want the div to provide vertical scrollbar in case of overflow (not to expand the height of containing cell!).
My current implementation **works fine on Chrome and Safari** but **not on IE and Firefox**!
Here is a sample code represents my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vuSAz/5/ (open it on IE and chrome to see the difference)

I'm looking for CSS solution (not using JS to resize).
I don't want to set fixed height for cells. I want the table to fit in the container div even if the container height is changed.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="cellHeader">Header 1</div>
            <div class="cellContent"></div>            
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="cellHeader">Header 2</div>
            <div class="cellContent"></div>            
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="cellHeader">Header 1</div>
            <div class="cellContent"></div>            
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="cellHeader">Header 2</div>
            <div class="cellContent">
                <div>sample content</div>
                <div>sample content</div>
                <div>sample content</div>
                <div>sample content</div>
                <div>sample content</div>
                <div>sample content</div>
                <div>sample content</div>
                <div>sample content</div>
                <div>sample content</div>
                <div>sample content</div>    
            </div>            
        </div>     
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="cellHeader">Header 1</div>
            <div class="cellContent"></div>            
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="cellHeader">Header 2</div>
            <div class="cellContent"></div>            
        </div>     
    </div>    
</div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}
.table{
    display:table;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.table-row{
    display:table-row;
}
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:5px;
    height:20%;
    width:50%;
}
.cellHeader{
    height:20px;
}
.cellContent{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:90%;
}
```

Comment: You could give `.cellContent` a `max-height`

Comment: I don't want to set fixed height for cells. I want the table to fit in the container div even if the container height is changed, therefore, I don't know the exact value to put on Height or Max-height. And max-height:90% ends up with same result on IE

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you want the cell scrollable

```
.cellContent{
overflow-x:hidden;
height:5em;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to set fixed height for cells. I want the table to fit in the container div even if the container height is changed, therefore, I don't know the exact value to put on Height or Max-height.

Comment: So you're asking for a fluid table inside a div with fluid cell height, each cell having a maximum height and if they go over have the ability to scroll the cell?  Sorry for the run on, I'm just trying to get the complete picture.

Comment: yes, if you check that fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/vuSAz/5/) on chrome and IE you will see the difference, I want IE to act same as chrome for scrolling cell content

Comment: I see.  I would use javascript to count the number of child elements or get the length.  If it is over a certain number then adjust the height of the parent element.  I tried IE 11 and Firefox and they scroll the same, but I see what you mean on Chrome.  I think the most universal solution would be JS but let me keep trying.  
[javascript counting elements](http://help.dottoro.com/ljsfamht.php)

Edit: I don't know why I didn't say this before, but I would get away from a table if you're needing variable heights.  CSS3 has column constants now, which would be a lot more easy to work with.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but this is only a sample to simulate the problem. This table have been used as part of a large webapp. I cannot change it to column structure.

Comment: You must only use CSS and HTML then?

Comment: No, while it is working on chrome and safari I assume there should be some tricks to make it work on IE and firefox as well without using JS. (I already implemented it with a JS function that calculates the height based on number of content's childs)

Comment: Ok, well good luck!  Sorry I wasn't much help to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would use *divisions* instead of *tables*, but that aside, i think I can help you. You seem to want a division that adds a scrollbar without making the height bigger. I think your problem is that when the scrollbar appears it makes the division bigger than it would be without the scrolllbar. Just apply the following css to the div we're talking about:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
moz-box-sizing:border-box;
```

This tells the browser that the width and height should display the true dimensions of the element. Let me give you some examples:

---

```
<div style="width:400px;padding:100px;border:20px solid #000">content</div>
```

The division above has a true width of 640px on the screen (*2 borders + 2 paddings + width*);

```
<div style="width:400px;padding:100px;border:20px solid #000;box-sizing:border-box">content</div>
```

The division above has a true width of 400px on the screen. the browser calculated (*2 borders + 2 paddings*) and substracted it from the width to decide what width the content should have.

Comment: I don't have problem with borders. My problem is that the cellContent div does not show V-scrollbar on IE while it does on chrome when it overflows. It expands the table cell height instead of scrolling!

Answer (score 0):

The browser makes a longer division without horizontal scrollbar because the text is formatted to the width:

```
a b c d e f g
```

becomes

```
a
b
c
...
```

You can avoid this behaviour by adding a css property to the text:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```